# To have `removeID` for jQuery like `removeClass`

Tags: jquery

How can you remove the attribute `id` by jQuery?

```
jQuery('a.no_flag_question').live('click', function(){
    jQuery.post('/codes/handlers/no_flag_question.php', 
        { question_id: jQuery(this).attr('rel') });
            $(".question_box").removeClass("yellow");   // problem here
            alert ("Question is now not spam.");
});
```

This code should remove the following yellow -attribute in

```
<div id="yellow" class="question_box">
```

However, this does not work. The reason is very likely the function `removeClass`.
I apparently use wrong function, since I want to use the ID.

Comment: Why are you removing an identifier? Seems like you are doing some strange business logic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$('.question_box').removeAttr('id')
```

More info at http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeAttr

Answer (score 6):

removeClass only exists because `class` is a multi-valued attribute... if you have a `<div class="one two three">` and you call `.removeClass("two")` on it, it should end up with `class="one three"`. `addClass` and `removeClass` exist to save you from doing all that work yourself. `id` isn't special in that way, so you just access it with `attr`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove class:

```
$('.question_box').removeClass('nameClass');
```

Remove id:

```
$('.question_box').removeAttr('id');
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the id too?

Comment: The first statement is used to delete a specific class. The second statement  is used to remove ID attribute. Use only the one you need.